# Call a function name from dictionary map

Tags: python

I want to call a function dynamically, but I didn't success.

```
available.append({
     'analysis_name': 'Category X Total Payment',
     'col_name': 'VALUE',
     'required_cols': ['Category','VALUE'],
     'agg':'SUM',
     'analysis_type': 'pareto-bar',
     'func': 'draw_pareto'})
available.append({
    'analysis_name': 'Category X Count',
    'col_name': 'Count',
    'required_cols': ['Category','VALUE'],
    'agg':'Count',
    'analysis_type': 'pareto-bar',
    'func': 'draw_pareto'})
```

I have an array which is mapping function names, and I want to call the function by user option like this:

```
def runAnalysis(self, analysis):
    required_cols = analysis['required_cols']
    agg = analysis['agg']
    col_name = analysis['col_name']
    analysis['data'] = self.draw_pareto(required_cols[0], required_cols[1], agg, col_name) // this line must be dynamically
    return analysis['data']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your data to contain the function:

```
available.append({
    'analysis_name': 'Category X Count',
    'col_name': 'Count',
    'required_cols': ['Category','VALUE'],
    'agg':'Count',
    'analysis_type': 'pareto-bar',
    'func': self.draw_pareto})
```

Then call it:

```
analysis['data'] = analysis['func'](required_cols[0], required_cols[1], agg, col_name) // this line must be dynamically
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can not change the dictionary to contain the function itself, instead of it's name, as suggested in other answers, when you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the function corresponding to the name:

```
func = getattr(self, analysis['func'])
analysis['data'] = func(required_cols[0], required_cols[1], agg, col_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python everything (`classes`, `functions` etc) is an object, if you want a `dict` to map from keys to functions use function objects.

```
def test():
    map = { 'a': func1, 'b': func2 }
    map['a']()

def func1(): pass
def func2(): pass
```